# Creating SharePoint Visual Webpart with Bootstrap

Tags: visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am creating a responsive sharepoint visual webpart. 
everything works fine and looks good but my mobile view is pretty much off. 
the controls doesn't shrink to the lowest mobile size..
i tried many times but still i have the same issue..

```
  <fieldset class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-8  col-md-3 " for="textinput">Name:
            </label>
            <div class="controls col-xs-8  col-md-7">                    
                <asp:TextBox MaxLength="50" runat="server" ID="txtTitle" CssClass="form-control">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
        </div>
        <!-- Select Basic -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-md-3 " for="selectbasic">Ano:
            </label>
            <div class="controls col-xs-8 col-md-2">

                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddYear" CssClass="form-control">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-md-3 " for="selectbasic">Mes:
            </label>
            <div class="controls col-xs-8 col-md-2">

                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddMonth" CssClass="form-control">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
        </div>
        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-md-3 " for="textinput">Tema de Salud:
            </label>
            <div class="controls col-xs-8  col-md-7">

                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="ddHealthTopic">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-md-3 " for="textinput">Unidad administrativa:(por sus siglas en ingles entre paréntesis)
            </label>
            <div class="controls col-xs-8  col-md-7">

                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="ddOrgUnit">                        
                </asp:DropDownList>

            </div>
        </div>



    </fieldset>
    <br />
 <div  class=" col-xs-10 col-md-10">
<div class="input-group" > 
       <span  class="input-group-btn">      
                       <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-primary" ToolTip="Buscar" runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Buscar" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />                
           </span>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine ....

Try to add (If its no there)

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

head section of your master page

Comment: does this affect any other places...i am using bootstrap in other pages as well...and it is a SharePoint Master Page...Just want to make sure if it doesn't disrupts other pages.....

Comment: @vinayak..it worked to one step closer, i can see one more screen size now...but one problem i have is the button at the end..in my desktop i want it to be aligned at the right side...but in smaller screens it is little off the frame to the right...i have the div aligned to right which works fine in all the screen sizes up to tablet view..but in smaller screen it goes out from the boundary.....

Comment: Wrap your entire code in class="row" 

        <div class="row">
        ///your webparts code goes here
       </div>